# Call R (native in Linux) from Wine

Tags: r, linux, wine

I have recompiled R for the Intel MKL library and it sits in my Linux o/s (RHEL) - it needs to be in Linux to enable me to work with my Xeon phi easily whether it be for recompiling or the like.

On the other side, I have some code that is running in Wine (namely metatrader4). This program needs to run in Wine as that particular program doesn't have a Linux build.

The aim: The metatrader4 code running in Wine needs to call the equivalent of Rterm.exe that is sitting in Linux.

What I have tried and problems: I have tried to call the R file using cmd (through .bat and script file), however, it seems to not open an interactive session of R - it opens and closes R (or doesn't open at all!) and so I am unable to work with the Linux native R session from Wine. I have also tried using the --interactive flag but no success.

Will appreciate any help/direction anyone can provide

Many thanks in advance,